# User opens application by touching received push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification

In my application I have three View Controllers, let's call them MainVC, ObjectsVC and EventsVC (sorry if you don't like such shortcuts). MainVC is initial VC of whole app and the rest are the TableVCs that contains lists with some objects.
This app supports Push Notifications that comes with "id" field:
- id = 0 -> app starts normally
- id = 1 -> app starts with ObjectsVC
- id = 2 -> app starts with EventsVC
How can I achieve transitions listed above when user taps incoming PN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be to return to the initial `viewController` and then to push the desired one. For example:

```
if id == 2 {
    let eventsVc = EventsVC()
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(eventsVc, animated: false)
}
```

In case the desired `viewController` is already in the navigation stack, you should check it's really there and `pop` to it.

It really depends on the desired navigation behavior.

Comment: And what if there is few more views between MainVC and ObjectsVC?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler;
```

you can get your notificationId via notification.request.content.userInfo